# How can I add Wildcard to the string in flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

The following code will give the current user whose role is Meet.

```
_currentUser["role"] == "Meet"
```

But in reality, I'd like to get the current user whose role is prefixed with Meet.
eg.MeetAdmin, MeetPec, like that.
Please help me how do I do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension on String:

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  bool hasPrefix(String prefix) {
    return substring(0, prefix.length) == prefix;
  }
}


void main() {
  final role = 'MeetPec';
  final invalidRole = 'PecMeet';
  
  print(role.hasPrefix('Meet')); // returns true
  print(invalidRole.hasPrefix('Meet')); // returns false
}
```

It assumes case-sensitive check, but you can tweak it to also support case-insensitive by adding `.toLowerCase()` to both prefix and the string itself.

**EDIT:**
As pointed out in the comments, we already have a `startsWith` method, this is definitely a way to go here:

```
void main() {
  final role = 'MeetPec';
  final invalidRole = 'PecMeet';
  
  print(role.startsWith('Meet')); // returns true
  print(invalidRole.startsWith('Meet')); // returns false
}
```

Comment: Why don't just use the [`startsWith` method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.3/dart-core/String/startsWith.html)?

Comment: @enzo of course, I just blindly added an answer based on the previous approaches without digging into what we are provided with already. For sure, using `startsWith` is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have precisely helped me. This is the best answer I've ever got.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if I understand your question property, you want to check if the current user role has the word "meet" in it.

If that's the case your can use contains to check if the role contains role

Example

```
if(_currentUser["role"].contains("meet") ) {
  //It contains meet
}else{
 //It does not contain meet
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This is the first time hearing the contains method.

Answer (score 0):

check this method it might help you. whenever you want to check or search you should convert string to lower case to compare then check

```
        bool getCurrentUserWithMeet() {
      Map<String, String> _currentUser = {
        'role': 'MeetAdmin',
      };

      final isCurrentUserContainsMeet =
          _currentUser['role']?.toLowerCase().contains('meet');
          
      return isCurrentUserContainsMeet ?? false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my first time of seeing such kind of approach.